# org.xml.sax.SAXException: operation description is missing parameter

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm invoking SOAP webservices with below Soap Message:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <login>
      <password>London</password>
      <role>M</role>
      <userName>Jon</userName>
    </login>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"
```

SOAPAction is using
"https://www.banking-payments.net/banks/services/BankManagerService/login".

But I am getting errors like this:

```
<soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
  <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
  <faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXException: operation description is missing parameter description!</faultstring>
  <detail><ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ukdc2-pc-smw01.worldpay.local</ns1:hostname></detail>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

Here is my WSDL excerpt for "login"

```
element name="login">
  <complexType>
    <sequence>
      <element name="loginRequest" type="tns2:LoginRequest"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
</element>

<complexType name="LoginRequest">
  <sequence>
    <element name="applicationType" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="mobileIdentificationNumber" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="password" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="role" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="userName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="valid" type="xsd:boolean"/>
    <element name="versionID" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
  </sequence>

  <wsdl:message name="loginRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="tns1:login" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:operation name="login">
    <wsdl:input message="impl:loginRequest" name="loginRequest"></wsdl:input>
  </wsdl:operation>

Note: Username, password and role are mandatory
```

Can anyone tell me what could be the reason for this error ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide all values for all parameter of the login() method in your WebService Implementation class.
Your SOAP Request message should be like following as per description in your WSDL:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" 
xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
<soapenv:Body>
<login>
  <applicationType>value</applicationType>
  <mobileIdentificationNumber>value</mobileIdentificationNumber>
  <password>London</password>
  <role>M</role>
  <userName>Jon</userName>
  <valid>true</valid>
  <versionID>1</versionID>
</login>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```